# How can I remove this error when I deploy my React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, hosting

Currently I have a functioning React app that I am able to run on `localhost:3000`. My current deployment process is as follows: I ran `npm run build`, and uploaded that file to my shared hosting provider.

I then added a .htaccess file with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then I added `"homepage": ".",` in the package.json. (I even tried to add the `"homepage": "http://websiteexample.com"`, instead of the . ).

From another post I seen, I even removed the forward slashes in my index.html.

None of this seems to work and gives me a blank page with the following error in the console:
 `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://website.com/static/js/main.f532f71f.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

**Question**: How can I deploy it? Is there something I am missing?

**UPDATE:** I just deployed another react app, it seems as though this process works fine, but the issue is coming from one of my files... just need to figure out which one

**UPDATE 2:** I found the file... the error that I am getting now is:
`Uncaught TypeError: (0 , kn.forwardRef) is not a function` What is this? Will update again soon.

**UPDATE 3:** I have a modal that takes props, which is making all these issues. BUT why does it fail to render once deployed, but works on localhost? Be back soon with more answers.

**Final Update:**
The error was coming from the following line"

```
{ props.accordion1_1 ?  <Accordion></Accordion> : <Typogrpahy></Typography>}
```

The accordion comes from React Material Ui. So I decided to add a useEffect to watch for the props.

Comment: Can you include a [mre] that shows the code that produces this error?

Comment: Hey Stephen, the error only shows up when I upload the build file to my shared hosting provider, anywhere else it doesn't show the error. Although I did find the problem, just updated my answer for the final time.

Comment: That should be posted as an answer rather than as an edit to your question. Please answer your own question by pressing the "Answer Your Question" button.  Then you can mark your answer as "accepted" which will remove it from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was coming from the following line:

```
{ props.accordion1_1 ?  <Accordion></Accordion> : <Typogrpahy></Typography>}
```

The accordion comes from React Material Ui. So I decided to add a useEffect to watch for the props.